# XML to DB using SQLXMLBulkLoad lib

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd

I have a pretty complicated XML that i need to load into MS SQL Server DB using a C# application. Am using the .NET standard SQLXMLBulkLoad library for doing this. The XML is given below.

```
<HouseInfo>
    <HouseNumber>1</HouseNumber>
    <HouseLog>
        <RoomInfo>
            <RoomNumber>1</RoomNumber>
            <Timestamp>2017-12-29T12:16:51</Timestamp>
            <Furnitures>
                <Table>
                    <Color>Blue</Color>
                    <Height>23</Height>
                </Table>
            </Furnitures>
            <ToolCounts>
                <Scope>1</Scope>
            </ToolCounts>
        </RoomInfo>

        <RoomInfo>
            <RoomNumber>2</RoomNumber>
            <Timestamp>2017-12-29T15:43:23</Timestamp>
            <Furnitures>
                <Table>
                    <Color>Black</Color>
                    <Height>35.2</Height>
                </Table>
            </Furnitures>
            <ToolCounts>
                <Scope>1</Scope>
            </ToolCounts>
            <Bathroom>
                <Code>1234</Code>
                <Faucets>3></Faucets>
            </Bathroom>
        </RoomInfo>

        <RoomInfo>
            <RoomNumber>2</RoomNumber>
            <Timestamp>2017-12-29T15:45:48</Timestamp>
            <Furnitures>
                <Table>
                    <Color>Red</Color>
                    <Height>98.56</Height>
                </Table>
            </Furnitures>
            <ToolCounts>
                <Scope>1</Scope>
            </ToolCounts>
            <Bathroom>
                <Code>1234</Code>
                <Faucets>2></Faucets>
            </Bathroom>
        </RoomInfo>
    </HouseLog>
</HouseInfo>
```

I created a XSD (schema) file and passed both XML & XSD to lib's **Execute** function.

Created a single table in DB to add all data tags as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSEINFO (House Number INT,
            RoomNumber INT,
            TimeStamp DateTime,
            Color VARCHAR(25),
            Height VARCHAR(25),
            Scope INT,
            Code INT,
            Faucet INT);
```

The goal here is to have every row contain **HouseNumber**, **RoomNumber** & **TimeStamp** as the 1st three columns. The rest of the column will contains data from the remaining tags inside **RoomInfo**.

I tried it myself, but couldn't find a way to make sure that 1st three columns are the above ones. I think this is a limitation with SQLXMLBulkLoad library. i.e., once the XML & XSD is passed into this lib, it's up to it's discretion on how to load the data to DB and we have no control. Is that statement correct?

Is there another approach by which i can accomplish this? i.e., to have all the data inside each **RoomInfo** tag in one row and the 1st three columns will be **HouseNumber**, **RoomNumber** & **TimeStamp**?

The reason why these are the 1st three columns is because then it will be easy to write a query to extract the data. As you see **HouseNumber** is unique to the whole XML. **RoomNumber** & **Timestamp** are unique to each **RoomInfo**. There can be N number of **RoomInfo** tags in a XML.

Am very new to XSD & DB programming and really struggling here. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how the SQLXMLBulkLoad does the job for you with your requirement. Here is the alternative. You can use [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=cinchoo) along with SqlBulkCopy to import your xml to database. Here is the working sample

```
static void BulkLoad1()
{
    string connectionstring = /* your db connection string */

    int houseNo = 0;
    using (var xr = new ChoXmlReader("your.xml").WithXPath("/HouseInfo")
        .WithField("HouseNumber", fieldType: typeof(int))
        )
    {
        houseNo = xr.First().HouseNumber;
    }

    using (var xr = new ChoXmlReader("your.xml").WithXPath("/HouseInfo/HouseLog/RoomInfo")
        .WithField("HouseNumber", fieldType: typeof(int), valueConverter: (o) => houseNo)
        .WithField("RoomNumber", fieldType: typeof(int))
        .WithField("Timestamp", fieldType: typeof(DateTime))
        .WithField("Color", xPath: "Furnitures/Table/Color", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("Height", xPath: "Furnitures/Table/Height", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("Scope", xPath: "ToolCounts/Scope", fieldType: typeof(int))
        .WithField("Code", xPath: "Bathroom/Code", fieldType: typeof(int))
        .WithField("Faucet", xPath: "Bathroom/Faucets", fieldType: typeof(int))
    )
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionstring))
        {
            bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.HOUSEINFO";
            bcp.EnableStreaming = true;
            bcp.BatchSize = 10000;
            bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
            bcp.NotifyAfter = 10;
            bcp.SqlRowsCopied += delegate (object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.RowsCopied.ToString("#,##0") + " rows copied.");
            };
            bcp.WriteToServer(xr.AsDataReader());
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm using VS 2010 and installed ChoETL via package manager. But everytime i do a Rebuild, it complains about missing namespace. If i try to re-install then package manager says that it's already installed. The error am getting is - Error 101 The type or namespace name 'ChoETL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it requires .net 4.5. Do u have them?

Comment: If i go to Help in VS 2010, the ABOUT box says "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.01590"

Comment: It's kind of crazy. I uninstalled and reinstalled it. And then immediately VS is able to recognize the ChoETL namespace. But as soon as i try to run the project or build it, the missing namespace error comes up.

Comment: Check and see target framework is set for your project. use this link for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: The latest i see in Target Framework drop down is .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile. I installed .NET 4.7 from MS site, but it still doesn't show up in drop down. Do i need to do anything else for it to show up there? Or is that a limitation with VS 2010?

Comment: unfortunately vs2010 can't support it. U need Visual Studio 2012 in order to utilize .NET 4.5.

Comment: So can you suggest another way of doing this in VS 2010? i.e., without using ChoETL.

Comment: well, you can. But it requires lot of work. First you need to load, parse xml file into objects. Then you will have to use the ObjectDataReader to convert them to DataReader. Finally use the SqlbulkLoad to upload the data from datareader. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Am marking yours as answer even though it didn't help me because of VS 2010. Please let me know if you have a solution that will work for VS 2010 with .NET Framework 3.5